# Make versus makes

Tags: gerunds, verb-agreement

Which of these is correct?

1. Adding 's' or 'es' to nouns **makes** them plural words.
2. Adding 's' or 'es' to nouns **make** them plural words.

Answer (score 2):

Actually "adding" is the main element of the subject, not "s" or "es".
(The) adding (of) s or es makes nouns plural words.